# How do I uncompress/unzip within Emacs

Tags: emacs, zip, dired

I would like to run unzip (or even zip) within dired or a dired-like buffer. Is there anything like this? I would like something similar as in the Nautilus file manager: i.e., selecting files and then pressing a keystroke to get these files into a new archive file.

Thank you

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You've got options...

To uncompress a .zip file, you just need to add to the variable `'dired-compress-file-suffixes`

```
(eval-after-load "dired-aux"
   '(add-to-list 'dired-compress-file-suffixes 
                 '("\\.zip\\'" ".zip" "unzip")))
```

Now the `Z` key in dired will recognize the .zip extension and uncompress a .zip archive.  Already supported are `gunzip`, `bunzip2`, `uncompress` and `dictunzip`.

If you want to mark files and add them to a .zip archive you can use the following to make `z` bound to zip the set of marked files:

```
(eval-after-load "dired"
  '(define-key dired-mode-map "z" 'dired-zip-files))
(defun dired-zip-files (zip-file)
  "Create an archive containing the marked files."
  (interactive "sEnter name of zip file: ")

  ;; create the zip file
  (let ((zip-file (if (string-match ".zip$" zip-file) zip-file (concat zip-file ".zip"))))
    (shell-command 
     (concat "zip " 
             zip-file
             " "
             (concat-string-list 
              (mapcar
               '(lambda (filename)
                  (file-name-nondirectory filename))
               (dired-get-marked-files))))))

  (revert-buffer)

  ;; remove the mark on all the files  "*" to " "
  ;; (dired-change-marks 42 ?\040)
  ;; mark zip file
  ;; (dired-mark-files-regexp (filename-to-regexp zip-file))
  )

(defun concat-string-list (list) 
   "Return a string which is a concatenation of all elements of the list separated by spaces" 
    (mapconcat '(lambda (obj) (format "%s" obj)) list " "))
```

Comment: doesn't 'Z' do it out-of-the-box? (or mark it with 'm' and then hit 'Z'). I recall it worked for me a while back. I saw it here:

http://xahlee.org/emacs/file_management.html

Comment: `Z` will compress the files, each of them individually.  It doesn't add them to an archive/zip.

Comment: It seems concat-string-list does not exist:
concat: Symbol's function definition is void: concat-string-list

Comment: Ok, I've implemented it:

(defun concat-string-list (list)
  "Return a string which is a concatenation of all elements of the list separated by spaces"
  (mapconcat '(lambda (obj) (format "%s" obj)) list " "))

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot I had that in my own helper functions, I'll add it to the answer code.

Comment: it also seems that 'dired-compress-file-suffixes is defined by dired-aux and not by dired itself. Which makes the eval-after-load not working. I changed "dired" by "dired-aux" and it now works ok.

Comment: I think the above code needs some escaping for filenames, try marking a few files like `2010_12_HEAD_Seminar (1).pdf` and see what happens.

Comment: In Emacs 25, you can use `string-join` from `subr-x` instead of `concat-string-list`.

Comment: I am experiencing the same as @monotux. Is there a way to compress files that have spaces in between names? Annoyingly several people tend to use spaces instead of underscores or dashes. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 24):

To zip files, open the directory in dired.  Mark the files you want to zip with `m`.  Then type

```
! zip foo.zip * <RET>
```

To extract an entire archive from dired you can mark a file and run `& unzip`, just as you would in a shell.

zip-archive mode will allow you to browse zip files in a dired-like fashion.  It should come with recent versions of GNU emacs and will be used by default when you visit a file with the .zip extension.  From this mode you can extract individual files into a buffer, and from there save them with `C-x C-s`.